# cyclically rotate a selected array in vim

Tags: vim

Is there an easy command in vim to cyclically rotate arrays?

For example, selecting "1, 2, 3" in the text and pressing a shortcut
should replace the selected text to "2, 3, 1".

Ideally the command should allow for arbitrary cyclic shifts.

Answer (score 4):

You mean something like:

```
function! s:Rotate(list, rot)
   let res = a:list[a:rot :] + a:list[: (a:rot-1)]
   return res
endfunction

xnoremap <silent> <c-x>r s<c-r>=join(s:Rotate(split(@", ', *'), v:count1), ', ')<cr><esc>gv
```

Visually select your list. Hit `CTRL-X` then `r` and tada!. If you want to rotate more than of one element at a time, type first the number of shifts you want (the number must be in between -len(list) and +len(list)) before `CTRL-X_r`

Comment: E120: Using <SID> not in a script context: s:Rotate
E116: Invalid arguments for function join(s:Rotate(split(@", ', *'), v:count1), 
', ')

Comment: You have to put all this code into a plugin, for instance `~/.vim/plugin/rotate_list.vim`, and let vim source it (for the first time,you can source it manually with a `:runtime plugin/rotate_list.vim`

Answer (score 3):

[Argumentative.vim](https://github.com/PeterRincker/vim-argumentative) plugin allows shifting arguments. The idea being you shift the first argument with an overly large count, e.g. 99.

```
99>,
```

This will move the first argument to the end of the array. Then you can get back to the first argument with a similar trick using a boundary motion, `[,`

```
99[,
```

You may also want to take a look a [sideways.vim](https://github.com/AndrewRadev/sideways.vim) which provides similar functionality to argumentative.vim.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if Vim has some kind of built-in "shifting technique" but I would recommend to use yank and put command, or even better to use [exchange.vim](https://github.com/tommcdo/vim-exchange). For more information watch this nice [video](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/swapping-two-regions-of-text-with-exchange-vim/) on [vimcast.org](http://vimcasts.org/).